# MySQL How do I create a trigger that selects from another table?

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project, and I had to make a few changes to a table in order to help speed I am working on a project, and I had to make a few changes to a table in order to help speed things up. I tried to create the following trigger, but it does not work and just gives me the standard #1064 you have an error in your syntax error.

```
create trigger _wc_insert_trigger before insert on widget_components
    set new.component_id = (select id from components c where c.part_no=new.part_no)
```

I've never worked with triggers before, and I don't really understand everything that I get from Google responses.things up. I tried to create the following trigger, but it does not work and just gives me the standard #1064 you have an error in your syntax error.

Any ideas on how to get something like this to work? I don't have the budget to go in and refactor the existing application to take into account this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 delimiter |
 create trigger wc_insert_trigger before insert on widget_components
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
     set new.component_id = (select id 
                             from components c 
                             where c.part_no=new.part_no);
 END
 |
 delimiter ;
```

Comment: This works if I add a BEGIN after FOR EACH ROW. Can you explain why?

Comment: @JimP: I forgot to add it. Corrected that.